# gnuplot: Hypertext with monospace?

Tags: gnuplot

Is there a way to show the hypertext label with monospace?
I would like to align some text and numbers in a hypertext label in a table like manner.
But I couldn't get a monospace font as the hypertext labels. If I add `font "Monospace,10"` I'll get an error message `... unexpected or unrecognized token`. Trying to use `"\t"` in the label was also not successful. I am using Win7/64, wxt-terminal, gnuplot 5.2.6. Any ideas?

My code:

```
### hypertext with monospace?
reset session

set title "Hypertext with monospace?" font "Monospace,20"

set samples 10
plot '+' u 1:($1**2):(sprintf("%10s% 10g\n%10s% 10g","SomeValue",$1,"Square",$1**2)) \
    w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb "red" notitle 
### end of code
```

The result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, the fonts need to be set with the terminal and cannot be set independently just for the hypertext labels.
So, if you set

```
set term wxt font "Monospace,12"
```

You'll get:

[image]

However,

```
set term qt font "Monospace,12"
```

doesn't give monospace hypertext labels in a `qt` terminal. I don't know why.