# How to show values upon mouse hover in Gnuplot in SVG?

Tags: svg, gnuplot

After noticing the interactive gnuplot graphic upon https://lwn.net/Articles/723818/ showing country names on a mouse hover, I am wondering how to simply show the values of the points in a plot.

For example I want to hover over the "daughter bar" in https://s.natalian.org/2020-08-24/mouse-hover.svg and see **60** clearly.

[image: SVG hover]

However right now it just shows co-ordinates IIUC. How do I fix this?

```
set term svg mouse standalone
reset
$heights << EOD
dad                     181
mom                     170
son                     100
daughter        60
EOD

unset key
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:*]

plot '$heights' using 2:xtic(1) with boxes
set output '/tmp/mouse-hover.svg'
replot
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for `hypertext`, check `help hypertext`.
You have to use `point` to anchor the hypertext.
Play with the pointsize (here `ps 3`) to change the area where the mouse will display the hypertext.
Since you probably don't want to display a colored point at the top of your box, make the color transparent, e.g. `lc rgb 0xff123456`.

Unfortunately, I haven't found (yet) anything in the gnuplot documentation how to make the font of this hypertext larger. The option `font ",30"` does not have any effect. If you find out please let me know. Apparently in wxt terminal you can do it (see [gnuplot: Hypertext with monospace?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55482054/7295599)).

**Code:**

```
### SVG standalone with hypertext
reset session
set term svg mouse standalone enhanced
set output 'tbSVGstandalone.svg'

$heights <<EOD
dad            181
mom            170
son            100
daughter        60
EOD

unset key
set boxwidth 0.5
set style fill solid
set yrange [0:*]

plot '$heights' u 2:xtic(1) w boxes,\
     '' u 0:2:2 w labels hypertext point pt 7 ps 3 lc rgb 0xff123456
set output
### end of code
```

**Result:** (screenshot of SVG in Firefox. It looks like I can't place a SVG here, at least I don't know how.)

[image]

Comment: How do I manipulate the hypertext string? i.e. Height: 60cms in the tooltip?

Comment: ... `...'' u 0:2:(sprintf("Height: %g cms",$2)) w labels hypertext...`